# React View is not rendered in React 0.14

Tags: javascript, deprecated, reactjs

I tried to iterate an object and create table rows dynamically in **React 0.14** like the below

```
 var msg = React.createClass({

render: function() {
   var profiles = [];
    $.map(profs, function(prof){
       profiles.push(<tr>
          <td>{prof.Name}</td>
          <td>{prof.Type}</td>
           </tr>)
```

and try to add this in

```
<table>
  <tbody>
        {profiles}
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

But it is **not rendering** and **does not throw any error** also.
I rendered like

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(msg, {data: this.model.attributes}), this.el);
```

If I remove "`{profiles}`" it is rendering other part of page correctly.
But if I use the same code in **React 0.13.2** with

```
React.render(React.createElement(msg, {data: this.model.attributes}), this.el);
```

It is working fine. 
And it will be more helpful if anybody suggest debugging tools for these kind of errors.

Comment: unless I'm missing something this looks ok, your bug is probably due to something we don't see here. Off topic it seems you don't understand the difference between each and map, since you are using it like each, also you could use es5's map

Comment: Just an observation: Why don't you assign the output of the `$.map` function to the `profiles` variable? `var profiles = $.map(profs, function(prof) { return (<tr>...</tr>); });` But this will probably not fix your problem.

Comment: I tried that way too.. But it was the same

Answer (score 0):

Just finished upgrading my app to 0.14, and I encountered renders silently failing when either the component itself, or one of it's child components had an undefined mixin. In my case it was react-router's deprecated mixins... but took me a long time to figure it out. React usually handles undefined or null values pretty gracefully, or at least with a warning, but apparently not when ti comes to mixins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the `map` method in your first code sample is never closed: the final `)` closes the `push`, which leaves `map` and its callback (i.e., `function(prof)`) unclosed.

[Here's a working component based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/cu2ued0f/1/) that renders correctly:

```
var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var profiles = $.map(this.props.profs, function (prof) {
      return (
        <tr key={prof.name}>
          <td>{prof.name}</td>
          <td>{prof.type}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {profiles}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

var profileObjects = [{name: 'Brendan Eich', type: 'Netscape'},
                      {name: 'Jordan Walke', type: 'Facebook'}
                     ];

ReactDOM.render(
  <ExampleComponent profs={profileObjects} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. In the jsfiddle you included "react-dom.js" and "react-with-addons.js" but didn't include react.js. But how it is working fine? and for this simple operation why I have to include "addons.js"?

Comment: In all honesty, I just forked the "[React Base Fiddle (JSX)](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)", which included both of those libraries. React is included in `react-with-addons.js`, which is why the fiddle is able to use `React.createClass`. None of the addons are used. Both React and ReactDOM are included because of [this change made in the new version of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#two-packages-react-and-react-dom). React is used for creating the class, and ReactDOM is used for actually rendering it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were the unclosed functions the problem, @Viuu -a? Or did the issue persist even after closing them?

Comment: Actually even after closing the was there. Then I tried to implement the same thing with fresh setup and it is working now. But Am not sure what I did wrong in the previous setup.